# Loop values for one go channel to other

Tags: go, goroutine

Could anyone please review my code and can check why I am facing a deadlock?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    myCh := make(chan int, 10)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    wg.Add(10)

    // READ ONLY
    go func(ch <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        value := <-myCh
        fmt.Println(value)
        wg.Done()
    }(myCh, wg)

    // send ONLY
    go func(ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            myCh <- i
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(myCh, wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

I want to send the loop values from SEND CHANNEL and OTHER CHANNEL should only recieve the values of each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reader go routine exits after the FIRST received data. You have to include a for loop into it to continously read that channel.

Secondly you don't need to call wg.Sync() in your outer loop, because it also decreases the waitgroup.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    myCh := make(chan int, 10)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    
    wg.Add(10)
    
    // READ ONLY
    go func(ch <-chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for value := range myCh { // this loop will read the channel continously
            fmt.Println(value)
            wg.Done()
        }
    }(myCh, wg)
    
    // send ONLY
    go func(ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            myCh <- i
        }
        //      wg.Done() <- This not needed here
    }(myCh, wg)
    
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("DONE")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding delta = 10 in `wg.Add(10)`, and call wg.Done() only twice.

You should either call `wg.Add(2)` or call `wg.Done()` ten times.

Right now the main function locks at `wg.Wait()` and waits for eight more `wg.Done()` calls.